# Remove OneDrive icon from Navigation Pane while keeping active use of OneDrive itself

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, group-policy, onedrive

Many users here ask how to get rid of OneDrive completely and these questions already have answers.

My situation is different. I want to **remove only OneDrive *icon*** from Navigation Pane in Windows Explorer. However, I want to **continue using OneDrive, I use it in an active way**, I just don't need the icon there.

I've already tried removing corresponding `OneDrive` Registry key in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Desktop\NameSpace`.

**It helps until I reboot or sign out**, then the icon re-appears as soon as OneDrive app starts in tray (I guess the OneDrive app re-creates missing entries on its startup).

- Currently I suppose that my only option is to write a script/scheduled task that will delete that Registry key every time it re-appears or, say, 1 minute after logon.
- Can you advise an alternative, 'cleaner' solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the value of `System.IsPinnedToNameSpaceTree` to `0` within registry key:

```
HKCR\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}
```

[image: Screenshot]

---

Although the mod held through restart & logoff/logon on Win 10 Home, the OP reports needing to modify key permissions to prevent OneDrve from resetting the value:
[image: Permissions]

- **For this key only**, under the current user account, add `Deny` for *Advanced Permission* `Set value` to be as less intrusive as possible

Comment: Thanks!! This worked, but only after I modified permissions for `HKCR\CLSID\{018D5C66-4533-4307-9B53-224DE2ED1FE6}` so that OneDrive app is not able to reset the values. Without that, the icon still reappears after logout/login, once `OneDrive.exe` process starts... With your permission, I will edit your answer to add the screenshot with correct registry key permissions.

Comment: INteresting. I had tested with a restart, and the setting held.

Comment: so on your machine - when OneDrive.exe starts, it does not revert everything as it thinks it should be? (It’s also worth noting that I have premium OneDrive subscription, however, it is highly unlikely that this behavior differs for free and premium accounts).

Comment: RIght. I had tested a Restart. Just tested logooff/logon. My mod stuck.  But I just edited to introduce your screenshot of modified permissions. Go ahead & add your screenshot..

Comment: just added, it’s pending community review. Thank you again for the solution!